# Declined flags do not show up in moderator history

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, moderation, low-quality-posts, moderator-queue

I've been working in the Very Low Quality moderator queue today, but noticed that when I decline a flag, it doesn't show up in [my moderator history](https://stackoverflow.com/admin/history/16587) (visible to SE and moderators only).

This is a bad thing, mostly because I sometimes it hit 'decline' when I really mean, "Delete", and that's a little awkward for everyone.  I seem to remember declinations being visible in my moderator history, and I assume it's gone due to the refactor.  Any chance we can get it back? It's helpful when I need to fix an oopsie I made.

Comment: I can see 3 declined VLC entries at the bottom of the page. And we don't exclude "declined" in any of the queries for the data, so appears strange to me that this happens. Do you have a recent example?

Comment: @Oded if you check my most recent history, I can say with certainty that there are 20 or more declined flags that should show up interspersed with the "Helpful" flags.  Given that this data is necessarily private, I'm not sure what I can post or what I can't. If you want, I can hit you up in the TL and show you specific examples.

Comment: I've noticed this regularly a few times since the flag changes, particularly around inappropriate spam flags on posts that do have other problems where I was in the habit of declining and then viewing the post from the history.

Answer (score 9):

Yesterday another moderator declined a flag and told me he did so in our private mod chatroom.  Looking at the post history itself, I was able to confirm that he was indeed the one who declined the flag.  But when I checked the moderator dashboard (/admin) I see his "last activity" as *January 10*:

[image: last activity]

Clicking that January 10 link gives me this mod's history, but the recent declined flag is not listed.

To me this is a major gap, because as a mod with little experience, I want to be able to see the sorts of things that my fellow moderators are declining, so that as a team we act consistently.  I also want my fellow mods to be able to easily see what *I am declining*, so that they can provide feedback to me if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

As of 6/14/2019, it appears this bug is no longer able to be reproduced. I have checked the same link and now Declinations show up.

Comment: I just declined a "rude or abusive" flag, and then deleted the flagged answer. Only the post deletion shows on my mod history. Special case?

Comment: it might be? /cc @timpost